# Why does Activity in Android restrict calling methods normally like other simple Classes?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am asking for "Why", the reasoning behind this behavior.

The question is not a Duplicate of other "How to" type questions.

```
// MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        

        fun mainFunction() {
            // code
        }
```

```
// AnotherClass.kt

class AnotherClass() {

    fun anotherFunction() {

    }
}
```

```
// SomeClass.kt

class SomeClass() {

    init {
        MainActivity().mainFunction() // unresolved reference ERROR
        AnotherClass().anotherFunction() // Works Fine!
    }
}
```

What is so different about Activity `Class` in Android? Why does Activity in Android restrict calling methods normally like other simple Classes?

Comment: This has nothing to with `Activity`. `mainFunction()` is a [local function](https://medium.com/tompee/idiomatic-kotlin-local-functions-4421f86ac864), visible only inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because activity it's an appcomponent managed by the OS. And methods like `onCreate` or `onResume` calling by OS. You just can decide what should be happened where this method will be called for operation system. For example:
you can release resources in the `onStop` or `onDestroy` methods.

That's because android app is working under Android OS(That have it's own rules).

For better understanding, I can recommend you to read the article:
[Application Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` instance acts like a system plugin. The plugin defines various hooks for the system to call during various state of the activity. Hooks allow developer to customize the activity behavior. For example, when the system transitions an activity into the created state, it calls the `onCreate` hook of your plugin so that you can provide a view for the system to render inside the activity. The plugin itself does not have full control of the lifecycle of the activity, it just customizes it.

To simplify the customization, so that you can make certain assumption about the state and you can get the data you need easier, the system defines a contract. The contract defines the order of the hook invocation and the set of fields/properties which must be assigned/removed before/after calling each hook.

For the code snippet in the question, you have instantialize an activity instance, but you have not fulfilled the contract, e.g. providing an activity context, etc. If you try to call the methods inherited from the `Activity` class, it is likely to crash since the assumptions made by the implementation is no longer valid and it is trying to access some fields/properties which have not been properly initialized.